# Creating nested lists using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, nested

Ive tried a lot of the answers to creating nested ul/li, but cant seem to get create one. Im very new to js.

the data is grabbed after the page loads, and comes in a format like this

```js
data = { 
  "key1": ["value1", value2", "value3"],
  "key2": ["value4", "value5", "value6"],
  "key2": ["value7"]
}
```

As a bonus, I was hoping to click on a key and drop down (expand) to show the values. But ive failed to get the data to load in the structure below. There can be any number of keys, with values(lists) of any length. also, the keys can be named anything.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    key1
    <ul>
      <li>value1</li>
      <li>value2</li>
      <li>value3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    key2
    <ul>
      <li>value4</li>
      <li>value5</li>
      <li>value6</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    key3
    <ul>
      <li>value7</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

i updated adding the jquery code ive been attempting. I did not include it because ive tried many variants to get the data in the nested structure above and am probably doing it wrong.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$.get('url', function(data){

            var $ul = $('<ul></ul>');

            function getList(item, $list) {

                $.each(item, function (key, value) {
                    var $li = $('<li />');
                    $li.append($('<a href="#">' + key + '</a>'));

                    var $subul = $("<ul/>");

                    $.each(value, function(i) {
                        var subli = $('<li/>')
                        .text(value[i])
                        .appendTo(subli);
                    });
                    $subul.append(subli);


                    $li.append($subul)

                });
            }
            getList(data, $ul);
            $ul.appendTo("div_containing_ul");
    });});
```

Comment: show us some code of what you tried so we can tell you whats wrong

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. You seem to be new to programming in general?; you Need to break your problem down into key components and try to understand what it is that you don't know. the first thing I would suggest you try to do is use `Object.keys(data)` and make a for loop using that to simply print `<ul><li>key1</li>...<li>keyN</li></ul>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An error and a missing append.

The `.appendTo(subli);` should really be `.appendTo($subul);` and at the end of the function you need to add the `$li` to the `$list`.

```js
data = {
  "key1": ["value1", "value2", "value3"],
  "key2": ["value4", "value5", "value6"],
  "key3": ["value7"]
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var $ul = $('<ul></ul>');

  function getList(item, $list) {

    $.each(item, function(key, value) {
      var $li = $('<li />');
      $li.append($('<a href="#">' + key + '</a>'));

      var $subul = $("<ul/>");

      $.each(value, function(i) {
        var subli = $('<li/>')
          .text(value[i])
          .appendTo($subul); // you need to append it to the $subul not the $subli
      });


      $li.append($subul).appendTo($list); // you need to append the $li to the $list

    });
  }
  getList(data, $ul);
  $ul.appendTo("#div_containing_ul");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div_containing_ul"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you all! i learned a bunch from this and was able to get jquery to do what i was looking for! the final here: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/23d0hz3b/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is recursion.
You don't know if that data will always be like that, if the nested levels will only be ever 2 levels deep.

I rewrote your example with recursion that takes in account an endless of levels of menus.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {


    function caller(data) {
        var $ul = $('<ul></ul>');
        recursiveCaller(data, $ul);
        return $ul;
    }

    function recursiveCaller(subdata, $parent) {
        if( typeof subdata === 'object' ) {
            for(var key in subdata) {
                $parent.text(key)
                var $sublist =  $('<ul></ul>');
                recursiveCaller(subdata[key], $sublist);
            }
        } else {
            var $child = $('<li></li>');
            $child.text(subdata)
            $parent.append($child);
        }
    }

    $.get('url', function () {
        var $menu = caller(data);
        $('#div_containing_ul').append($menu);
    });
});
```

This could easily deal with a structure like

```
var data = {
    'key1': ['val1', 'val2', 'val3'],
    'key2': [
        {'key2': ['val4', 'val5', 'val6']},
        'val5',
        'val6'],
    'key3': [
        {
            'key2':
                {
                    'key2': [
                        'val4',
                        {
                            'key2': ['val4', 'val5', 'val6']
                        },
                        'val6'],
                    0: 'val5',
                    1: 'val6'
                }
        }]
};
```

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

A short recursive version giving good results:

```
function buildList(data) {
    var $ul = $('<ul></ul>');
    for (const key in data) {
        var $child = $('<li></li>');
        $ul.append($child)
        if (typeof data[key] === 'object') {
            $child.text = $child.text(key);
            $child.append(buildList(data[key]));
        } else {
            $child.text = $child.text(key + ' : ' + data[key]);
        }
    }
    return $ul;
}
```

I feed my function with an array of objects containing a timestamp, a Partner object, and the Partner object containing a Company object; the result looks like this:

```
0
    timestamp : 1587732029600
    partner
        id : 0
        name : Name1
        email : a@b.com
        company
            id : 0
            name : SomeCompany1
1
    timestamp : 1587732029600
    partner
        id : 1
        name : Name2
        email : c@d.com
        company
            id : 1
            name : SomeCompany2
```